# UICollectionView cells being skipped

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create CollectionView similar to 500px app.

**App logic**: After app is launched, CollectionView loads empty cells(around 100), then when user scrolls down, cells are filled with image. At the end of view, new batch of empty cells are created(Load More). Images are pulled from Instagram, 20 per call.

**Problem:** When new images are pulled(async), cell rendering continues and usually it manages to create 3-5 empty cells before next batch of images are available.

**Question:** Is there any solutions for this problem? Maybe there's a better way to achieve this?

Code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

ALPhotoCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"photo" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

if (indexPath.row < [self.photos count]) {
    cell.photo = self.photos[indexPath.row];

}

if (indexPath.row == [self.photos count]-6) {
    [ALLoadMore loadMore:self.nextPage input:self.photos completionHandler:^(NSArray *newLoad, NSString *next) {
        self.photos = newLoad;
        self.nextPage = next;
        NSLog(@"%@", self.nextPage);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //[self.collectionView reloadData];
                if ([self.photos count] > indexPath.row) {
                    cell.photo = self.photos[indexPath.row];
                    NSLog(@"call");
                }
                NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[self.photos count]);
            });
    }];
}

return cell;}
```

For now cell count is a static number:120